# Getting the result of aggregate functions in Esqueleto

Tags: haskell, yesod, persistent, esqueleto

Say I have the following model:

```
Person
    stackOverflowUser Bool
    age Int Maybe
```

Using Esqueleto (& Yesod), say I want to get the average age of Stack Overflow users. I'd like to make a function with the type signature:

```
userAge :: Handler (Maybe Int)
```

So far, I have the following:

```
userAge :: Handler [Value (Maybe Int)]
userAge = runDB $
    select $
    from $ \person -> do
    where_ (person ^. PersonStackOverflowUser ==. val True)
    return joinV $ avg_ (person ^. PersonAge)
```

That gets me [Value (Maybe Int)], but I need to get down to "Maybe Int". I tried doing

```
mapM_ unValue userAge
```

But for some reason, doing so raised a type error, giving me [Maybe ()] rather than [Maybe Int]... Additionally, I think that the last line in the above code should have:

```
person ?. PersonAge
```

rather than

```
person ^. PersonAge
```

since PersonAge can be NULL, but changing it gives me a type error since:

```
avg_ :: (PersistField a, PersistField b) => expr (Value a) -> expr (Value (Maybe b))
(^.) :: (PersistEntity val, PersistField typ) => expr (Entity val) -> EntityField val typ -> expr (Value typ)
(?.) :: (PersistEntity val, PersistField typ) => expr (Maybe (Entity val)) -> EntityField val typ -> expr (Value (Maybe typ))
```

This is probably easier than I'm making it out to be, but I can't find examples anywhere online for using aggregate functions in Esqueleto, and I'm pretty new to Haskell so I'm having trouble figuring it out.

I suppose I could just use raw SQL, but if it's possible I'd like to do this using Esqueleto.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it! Finally wrapped my head around the type errors and came up with this:

```
import Safe (headMay)
import Control.Monad (join)
import Database.Esqueleto
-- other misc Yesod imports

userAge :: Handler (Maybe Int)
userAge = do
    a <- runDB $ select $
                 from $ \person -> do
                 where_ (person ^. PersonStackOverflowUser ==. val True)
                 return $ joinV $ avg_ (person ^. PersonAge)
    return $ join (headMay (map unValue a))
```

The "person ^. PersonAge" doesn't appear to cause any issues; I tested it on null and non-null values. I suppose the "?." operator is reserved for other situations.

Hopefully this saves someone else some time figuring it out!